# How do I write a regexp that matches the beginning of a line, a bunch of numbers, and then at least one space?

Tags: regex, match, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to remove numbers from the beginning of my string, but only if they are followed by at least one space.  I came up with the regex

```
/^\d+[:space:]/
```

except it is working too well.  Below it is matching the expression when it should not

```
2.4.0 :032 > line = "1sb    212"
 => "1sb    212"
2.4.0 :033 > line =~ /^\d+[:space:]/
 => 0
```

It should not match the expression because the first word, "1sb" has a number but the number if not followed by a space.  How can I adjust my expression so that it only matches one or more numbers followed by at least one space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the POSIX character class into a bracket expression:

```
/^\d+[[:space:]]/
     ^         ^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/KDHIApBvpK)

Otherwise, the `[:space:]` is treated as  a regular character class, and matches a single char, either `:`, `s` (`1sb` has `s` after the digit), `p`, `a`, `c` or `e`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be:

```
/^\d+\s+/
```

Notice that the `\s+` captures not only spaces, but tabs and line-breaks too. This might be important for your case.